# Display an image from Bayer's format to rgb format

Tags: c++, qt, rgb, qimage

I have to display the image captured from a camera in QtGui. I am reading the image from the camera and storing it in a unsigned char array. And Using the QImage i am constructing the image back in the GUI. The image is in bayers format.How to convert bayer to rgb format in qt?

**Code**
*loading the data and displaying *

```
QImage image((const unsigned char*)data,imageWidth,imageHeight,QImage::Format_Indexed8); 

this->scene->addPixmap((QPixmap::fromImage(image)).scaled(QSize((int)scene->width(),(int)scene->height()),Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,Qt::SmoothTransformation));
```

Comment: The similar [problem](http://www.qtforum.org/article/27601/grayscale-image-from-an-unsigned-char-table.html?s=0df3007bf44245b4590391e83e3e62aa02d46f3a#post95156) with the solution

Comment: Thanks you for the link.Yet i couldnot get how to set a color for the image i capture from camera

Comment: I referred the link and added the colortable. Yet the image is displayed in grayscale :(

Comment: In which format is the image data in the char array?

Comment: How about the solution? The above link died.